# Appending JSON values to search results div

Tags: jquery, json

I'm attempting to append the results of a search query to a div, but getting the `[object Object]` result. How can I parse this this json object and retrieve/display only the `title` and `permalink` from the result?

**json request**

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {
 var q = $("#searchterm").val();
 //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
 if(q.length > 3){
    ajax_search();
 }
 //Send search query
 function ajax_search(){
 $.getJSON("http://url-to-search?q=" + q, {
          dataType:'jsonp'
   },
 //Get results and make 'em look good
 function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $("#results").empty();
   $("#results").append("Results for <b> " + q + "</b>");
     $.each(data.query.search, function(i, data) {
         $("#results").append(data);
     });
  });
 }
});
```

**sample json**

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "data": [{
        "id": "/folder/bob-jones/",
        "image": "https://image-url.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/bob-jones/",
        "text": "lots of text description here",
        "title": "Bob Jones",
        "type": "Employee"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the data.data[0].title and /or data.data[0].permalink?

Comment: `data.query.search`, i think it should be `data.data` and inside function  `data.title` some think like... 

`$.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
         $("#results").append(data.title+" "+data.permalink);
     });`

Comment: @AswinRamesh - That works. If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Matt done... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.query.search, 
I think it should be data.data and inside function data.title some think like... `$.each(data.data, function(i, data) { 
  $("#results").append(data.title+" "+data.permalink); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As I don't have your URL to test this will be just a placeholder example:

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {
 var q = $("#searchterm").val();
 //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
 if(q.length > 3){
    ajax_search();
 }
 //Send search query
 function ajax_search(){
 $.getJSON("http://url-to-search?q=" + q, {
          dataType:'jsonp'
   },
 //Get results and make 'em look good
 function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $("#results").empty();
   $("#results").append("Results for <b> " + q + "</b>");
     $.each(data.query.search, function(i, data) {
           alert(data.data[i].title);
     });
  });
 }
});
```

Anyway, same concept as originally posted.

https://jsfiddle.net/2kcdhbmy/2/

---

Just created a JSFiddle for you:

```
var data = {
    "count": 50,
    "data": [{
        "id": "/folder/bob-jones/",
        "image": "https://image-url.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/bob-jones/",
        "text": "lots of text description here",
        "title": "Bob Jones",
        "type": "Employee"
    }]
}

alert(data.data[0].title);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kcdhbmy/

Comment: I need to be able to loop through multiple data entries, not just the first.

Comment: Modified example. Fiddle modified as well, this is just an example as I don't have a URL to test against.